# Azure Table Storage Partition Key

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Two somewhat related questions.

1) Is there anyway to get an ID of the server a table entity lives on?
2) Will using a GUID give me the best partition key distribution possible? If not, what will?

we have been struggling for weeks on table storage performance. In short, it's really bad, but early on we realized that using a randomish partition key will distribute the entities across many servers, which is exactly what we want to do as we are trying to achieve 8000 reads per second. Apparently our partition key wasn't random enough, so for testing purposes, I have decided to just use a GUID. First impression is it is waaaaaay faster.

Really bad get performance is < 1000 per second. Partition key is Guid.NewGuid() and row key is the constant "UserInfo". Get is execute using TableOperation with pk and rk, nothing else as follows:    TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve(pk, rk); return cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation). We always use indexed reads and never table scans. Also, VM size is medium or large, never anything smaller. Parallel no, async yes

Comment: Saying performance is "really bad" doesn't really provide any information. No reference point whatsoever. Please provide objective data: VM size, # of instances, a bit of sample code showing how you're attempting to do your reads, whether you're doing parallel reads, which language SDK, etc. Also: Please document what your partition+row key schema is, and how you're then doing lookups, as this could have an impact on your performance as well.

Comment: It would be much better to edit your question than embed additional info in comments, especially with unformatted code.

Answer (score 11):

As other users have pointed out, Azure Tables are strictly controlled by the runtime and thus you cannot control / check which specific storage nodes are handling your requests. Furthermore, any given partition is served by **a single server**, that is, entities belonging to the same partition cannot be split between several storage nodes (see [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx))

*In Windows Azure table, the PartitionKey property is used as the partition key. All entities with same PartitionKey value are clustered together and they are served from a single server node. This allows the user to control entity locality by setting the PartitionKey values, and perform Entity Group Transactions over entities in that same partition.*

You mention that you are targeting 8000 requests per second? If that is the case, you might be hitting a threshold that requires very good table/partitionkey design. Please see the article "[Windows Azure Storage Abstractions and their Scalability Targets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/04/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx)"

The following extract is applicable to your situation:

*This will provide the following scalability targets for a single storage account created after June 7th 2012.*

- *Capacity – Up to 200 TBs*
- *Transactions – Up to 20,000 entities/messages/blobs per second*

As other users pointed out, if your PartitionKey numbering follows an incremental pattern, the Azure runtime will recognize this and group some of your partitions within the same storage node.

Furthermore, if I understood your question correctly, you are currently assigning partition keys via GUID's? If that is the case, this means that every PartitionKey in your table will be unique, thus every partitionkey will have no more than 1 entity. As per the articles above, the way Azure table scales out is by grouping entities in their partition keys inside independent storage nodes. If your partitionkeys are unique and thus contain no more than one entity, this means that Azure table will scale out only one entity at a time! Now, we know Azure is not that dumb, and it groups partitionkeys when it detects a pattern in the way they are created. So if you are hitting this trigger in Azure and Azure is grouping your partitionkeys, it means your scalability capabilities are limited to the smartness of this grouping algorithm.

As per the the scalability targets above for 2012, each partitionkey should be able to give you 2,000 transactions per second. Theoretically, you should need no more than 4 partition keys in this case (assuming that the workload between the four is distributed equally).

I would suggest you to design your partition keys to group entities in such a way that no more than 2,000 entities per second per partition are reached, and drop using GUID's as partitionkeys. This will allow you to better support features such as Entity Transaction Group, reduce the complexity of your table design, and get the performance you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Answering #1: There is no concept of a *server* that a particular table entity lives on. There are no particular servers to choose from, as Table Storage is a massive-scale multi-tenant storage system. So... there's no way to retrieve a server ID for a given table entity.

Answering #2: Choose a partition key that makes sense to your application. just remember that it's partition+row to access a given entity. If you do that, you'll have a fast, direct read. If you attempt to do a table- or partition-scan, your performance will certainly take a hit.

Comment: I understand that partition+row key make a direct hit, but it seems the partition keys are clumped on the same server (hence question #1) as they are loaded all at the same time. Will using a GUID provide the best partitioning?

Comment: How exactly does the partitioning strategy work? Is there a link somewhere with complete details? Apparently loading PKs sequentially will put them on the same server making making access much slower then if they were better distributed.. So, PKs of 1,2,3,4,5,6 will most likely end up on the same server. I am trying to avoid this, which is why I am testing with a GUID.

Comment: Like I said: there's no such concept as a server with table storage. Sequential partition keys do not correlate to partitions being stored together.

Comment: For reference, start with Brad Calder's Azure Storage [whitepaper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/11/21/windows-azure-storage-a-highly-available-cloud-storage-service-with-strong-consistency.aspx).

Comment: OK, issue with terminology. The issue is sequential PKs may likely end up on the same partition, thus reducing access speeds. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667360/azure-table-partitioning-strategy

Comment: Sequential partition keys each go to a separate partition. *Partitions*... are *partitioned*... by *partition key.* Different partition keys are in different partitions.

Answer (score 0):

See 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx for more info on key selection (Note the numbers are 3 years old, but the guidance is still good).

Also this talk can be of some use as far as best practice : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/WAD-B406#fbid=lCN9J5QiTDF.

In general a given partition can support up to 2000 tps, so spreading data across partitions will help achieve greater numbers. Something to consider is that atomic batch transactions only apply to entities that share the same partitionkey.  Additionally, for smaller requests you may consider disabling Nagle as small requests may be getting held up at the client layer.

From the client end, I would recommend using the latest client lib (2.1) and Async methods as you have literally thousands of requests per second. (the talk has a few slides on client best practices)

Lastly, the next release of storage will support JSON and JSON no metadata which will dramatically reduce the size of the response body for the same objects, and subsequently the cpu cycles needed to parse them. If you use the latest client libs your application will be able to leverage these behaviors with little to no code change.