# Exploring the data from Azure Table Storage within Azure Cloud itself

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have created data in Azure Table Storage, but I am not able to view the loaded data in Table Storage without logging in to Azure Storage Explorer.

I want to view the data loaded within Azure Table Storage from the Azure Cloud portal (`portal.azure.com`). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 8):

1. From the azure portal you will need to navigate to the storage
   accounts.
2. From storage accounts select storage account type (i.e,
   tables, etc.) in the left-hand navigation panel
3. From the navigational panel select the storage browser and enjoy

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be any way to do this from within the Azure Portal.  I would suggest using the Azure Storage Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to view the table entity, [Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) is a good choice.

> we are facing some problems as like [PartitionKey was not specified in azure table storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325736/partitionkey-was-not-specified-in-azure-table-storage)

As I mentioned in your another [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325736/partitionkey-was-not-specified-in-azure-table-storage), [azure table entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model) should have  PartitionKey,RowKey properties. The following is the snippet from [Azure official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model).

> An entity always has the following system properties:
>
> - PartitionKey property
> - RowKey property
> - Timestamp property
>     These system properties are automatically included for every entity in a table.
>
> **The names of these properties are reserved and cannot be changed**. The developer is responsible for inserting and updating the values of PartitionKey and RowKey. The server manages the value of Timestamp, which cannot be modified.
>
> must include the **PartitionKey** property in every insert, update, and delete operation.
>
> must include the **RowKey property** in every insert, update, and delete operation.

Answer (score 1):

From the current Azure Portal UI looks like you can view Table data by: selecting your storage account > select 'Storage browser' from left side nav > Select 'Tables' and select your '' in question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

---

[From the main menu select SQL Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Baiu3.jpg)

---

[Select SQL Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCTuf.jpg)

---

[Enter your username and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee5EX.jpg)

---

[Voila! You will see your tables on the middle pane.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlpwU.jpg)
You can write your select, insert, update and delete SQL
If you click the Run button you will see the response below.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).